# Submit data if validation does not fail (PHP, MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, forms, submit, registration

so I'm working on a registration script and I haven't figured out yet how to realize preventing data from being submitted if the form input is invalid.

I have a name field, email field and password field. All three have their own validation. The code looks like this:

```
    <form action="config.php" method="post">
    Benutzername:<br>
    <input type="Text" autofocus name="username" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST["username"])) echo $name; ?>">
    <span class="req"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span><br><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST["email"])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>">
    <span class="req"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br><br>
    Passwort:<br>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="">
    <span class="req"><?php echo $passErr;?></span><br><br>
    <input type="Submit" name="send" value="Absenden">
</form>
```

The validation takes place above:

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $nameErr = "Dieses Feld darf nicht leer bleiben.";
        $name = "";
    } else {
        $nameCheck = false;
        $nameErr = "";
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"]) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Bitte eine gültige Email-Adresse angeben.";
        $email = "";
    } else {
        $emailCheck = false;
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $emailErr = "";

    }

    if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $passErr = "Bitte geben Sie ein Passwort an.";
        if(!preg_match('~^(?=.*\d.*\d)[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%*]{6,}$~', $_POST['password'])) {
            $passErr = "Das Passwort muss mindestens zwei Ziffern enthalten und aus 6 Zeichen bestehen.";
        }
    } else {
        $passwordCheck = false;
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $passErr = "";
    }

}

if($emailCheck != true && $passwordCheck != true && $nameCheck != true) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

So, if everything is completed properly, the form should redirect to config.php.

But with this code, I can leave all labels empty and it submits anyway...

Also I have the check on config.php that looks up in the database if email or user is already registered. How can I implement this check on my form page (index.php)?

Thanks in advance! I hope I did everything right here..

Comment: You will have to do your validation in javascript, not php... PHP requires a new request (the submit-action), while javascript can check everything before performing the actual form-submit. Google for 'Javascript form validation' to find out more.

Comment: do you set initial values for the `$emailCheck, $passwordCheck, $nameCheck` variables?

Comment: Yes, I do:

$nameErr = $emailErr = $passErr = "";

$nameCheck = $emailCheck = $passwordCheck = true;

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 


 if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

        if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
            $nameErr = "Dieses Feld darf nicht leer bleiben.";
            $name = "";
        } else {
            $nameCheck = false;
            $username =$_POST['username'];
            $nameErr = "";
        }

        if (empty($_POST["email"]) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $emailErr = "Bitte eine gültige Email-Adresse angeben.";
            $email = "";
        } else {
            $emailCheck = false;
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $emailErr = "";

        }

        if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
            $passErr = "Bitte geben Sie ein Passwort an.";
            if(!preg_match('~^(?=.*\d.*\d)[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%*]{6,}$~', $_POST['password'])) {
                $passErr = "Das Passwort muss mindestens zwei Ziffern enthalten und aus 6 Zeichen bestehen.";
            }
        } else {
            $passwordCheck = false;
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $passErr = "";
        }

}
?>
```

Comment: What does (isset($_POST['send'])) check? It submits incomplete data anyway.

Comment: it checks either from is submitted or not!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $emailCheck = true;
    $passwordCheck = true;
    $nameCheck = true;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $nameErr = "Dieses Feld darf nicht leer bleiben.";
        $name = "";
    } else {
        $nameCheck = false;
        $nameErr = "";
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"]) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Bitte eine gültige Email-Adresse angeben.";
        $email = "";
    } else {
        $emailCheck = false;
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $emailErr = "";

    }

    if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $passErr = "Bitte geben Sie ein Passwort an.";
        if(!preg_match('~^(?=.*\d.*\d)[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%*]{6,}$~', $_POST['password'])) {
            $passErr = "Das Passwort muss mindestens zwei Ziffern enthalten und aus 6 Zeichen bestehen.";
        }
    } else {
        $passwordCheck = false;
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $passErr = "";
   }

}

if($emailCheck != true && $passwordCheck != true && $nameCheck != true) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: the code is correct, you should check the values that are submitted/received `var_dump($_POST)`. I assumed `config.php` is the name of the file itself, is that correct?

Comment: config.php is the following site, index.php is the register script file called.

Comment: Your form is sent to `config.php` on submitting. This means the validation checks you perform are not executed at that point.